# How to generate credentials of twitter/facebook/instagram just with python script

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, analytics, twitter-oauth

If I have login and password for above mentioned websites. How to get
credentials for those website so that i can use them to update status / delete etc. I am aware of twitters tweepy and facebooks graph api but i need to know how to generate credentials with just login and password to data analytics. 
Thank you.

Comment: The Facebook OAuth implementation requires user interaction; If you want a Facebook user access token, then you need to send the user through the login flow. You are explicitly forbidden from trying to “log in” anywhere in any automated fashion using a user’s credentials directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact the best way of communication to any website in Your code is using their API. API's usually have some restrictions , but they are suitable if you don't need some thing out of this restrictions.
but if You don't want to use that APIs and you want to communicate with this websites in your python script. I think the best way is to use python [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) library, it opens you're browse automatically and do what ever You wrote in Your script code.

Comment: Can You suggest some website where i can get script to generate such keys. I tried using selenium python yet I'm not able to generate keys.

Answer (score 0):

If by having a username and password, you mean a regular user's username and password, then you can't generate it for yourself. You'll need to use their generator. For example, https://developer.twitter.com/en/apply-for-access